# Cannot modify header information - header already sent (CPT related)

Tags: custom-post-types

Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /wp-includes/class-wp-post-type.php:613) in /wp-includes/functions.php on line 6029

This error has seemed to follow me around since WP 5.3 where 'supports' needs to be an array. I've been able to successfully clear out the error for a small handful of sites by changing the order of the CPT args (throwing 'supports' at the end), but on others, the error still persists. I've always used an array for 'supports', but for some reason, this error is still persisting... Maybe it's something else in the CPT? I know it's the CPT for sure because removing the CPT code resolves the error. Can anyone tell me what I'm missing?

```
function rich_review() {

$labels = array(
    'name'                  => _x( 'Reviews', 'Post Type General Name', 'text_domain' ),
    'singular_name'         => _x( 'Review', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'text_domain' ),
    'menu_name'             => __( 'Reviews', 'text_domain' ),
    'name_admin_bar'        => __( 'Reviews', 'text_domain' ),
    'archives'              => __( 'Review Archives', 'text_domain' ),
    'attributes'            => __( 'Review Attributes', 'text_domain' ),
    'parent_item_colon'     => __( 'Parent Item:', 'text_domain' ),
    'all_items'             => __( 'All Items', 'text_domain' ),
    'add_new_item'          => __( 'Add New Item', 'text_domain' ),
    'add_new'               => __( 'Add New', 'text_domain' ),
    'new_item'              => __( 'New Item', 'text_domain' ),
    'edit_item'             => __( 'Edit Item', 'text_domain' ),
    'update_item'           => __( 'Update Item', 'text_domain' ),
    'view_item'             => __( 'View Item', 'text_domain' ),
    'view_items'            => __( 'View Items', 'text_domain' ),
    'search_items'          => __( 'Search Item', 'text_domain' ),
    'not_found'             => __( 'Not found', 'text_domain' ),
    'not_found_in_trash'    => __( 'Not found in Trash', 'text_domain' ),
    'featured_image'        => __( 'Featured Image', 'text_domain' ),
    'set_featured_image'    => __( 'Set featured image', 'text_domain' ),
    'remove_featured_image' => __( 'Remove featured image', 'text_domain' ),
    'use_featured_image'    => __( 'Use as featured image', 'text_domain' ),
    'insert_into_item'      => __( 'Insert into item', 'text_domain' ),
    'uploaded_to_this_item' => __( 'Uploaded to this item', 'text_domain' ),
    'items_list'            => __( 'Items list', 'text_domain' ),
    'items_list_navigation' => __( 'Items list navigation', 'text_domain' ),
    'filter_items_list'     => __( 'Filter items list', 'text_domain' ),
);
$args = array(
    'label'                 => __( 'Review', 'text_domain' ),
    'description'           => __( 'Rich reviews', 'text_domain' ),
    'labels'                => $labels,
    'taxonomies'            => 'rich_review_tax',
    'hierarchical'          => false,
    'public'                => true,
    'show_ui'               => true,
    'show_in_menu'          => true,
    'menu_position'         => 5,
    'show_in_admin_bar'     => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
    'can_export'            => true,
    'has_archive'           => true,
    'exclude_from_search'   => false,
    'publicly_queryable'    => true,
    'capability_type'       => 'page',
    'supports'              => array('title', 'editor'),
);
register_post_type( 'reviews', $args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'rich_review', 0 );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to figure out what's causing this error. For some reason, 'taxonomies' is looking for an array, even if I only have one taxonomy I'm relating it to. Changing the 'taxonomies' value like so resolved the PHP error: `'taxonomies' => array( 'rich_review_tax' ),`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it'll help but try putting the supported functions into their own variable array like you do with labels.

```
$supports = array( 
     'title',
     'editor'
);
```

Then, under $args, use `'supports' => $supports`.

I use that for 'labels', 'supports' and 'taxonomies'.

Should also note that it's good practice to make your variables a bit more unique to the post-type. So `$revw_labels, $revw_supports, $revw_taxonomies`and make sure you input custom `text_domains` instead of using the generic placeholder.  That'd be the text domain of either your plugin or theme.

Comment: It does functionally work, but does not resolve the PHP error. Thanks for the tip on the text domain.

Comment: I actually forgot to mention that I use arrays for labels, supports and taxonomies - got caught up in the text domain and variable names and forgot to break that down further.  Sorry.